# How to copy my log4j logs to email using javamail API ans log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have created a xml validating tool with log4j logs to get the Error Details using java.
Now I need to mail the Entire Content of what I am getting in my log4j logfiles( with background color in mail).

Please guide me to achieve this,and I have attached the screenshot of my log4j logfile and email format.

[image: Screenshot for log and email]

Below are the piece of my java code.

Log 4j Properties:

```
#Log to Console as STDOUT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss}     %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
#Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'dd/MM/yyyy
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

Code for java mail:

```
MimeMessage message = new   
MimeMessage(session);                                   
m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to1));
String htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title>"
                        + "</head><body><center><table " 
                        +"   border-width:5px;  "
                        +"   border-style:dotted;"
                        +"border-style: double;"
```

.
.
.
.

Comment: Do you want to attach the log file with your mail or you have different requirement?

Comment: Thank you for reply.Actually my exact requirement is to email the error log details (not as an attachment of error log file) being generated by my log4j logger.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j has SMTP appender to send emails, I am providing an xml lof4j example you can change it to properties and try... thanks

```
<appender name="ErrorEmailAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="mail.mydomain.com" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="password" />
    <param name="From" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
    <param name="To" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
    <param name="Subject" value="Log of messages" />
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
    <param name="EvaluatorClass" value="TriggerLogEvent" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.foo.mailer">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorEmailAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Thank you rupesh.I have tried online to convert it to log4j.properties.but i couldnt get a possible ways.Can you please guide me to convert it to properties?Thank you

Comment: My updated log4l.properties:
    #CONFIGURE SMTP
    log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=ilavarasan.mbsjgr@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=Flower@123
    log4j.appender.email.From=ilavarasan.mbsjgr@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.To=ilavarasan.mtss@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.Subject=Log of messages
    log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
Its Still Not triggering the logs.please help.

Comment: Continuation:
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
# INFO level will be logged
log4j.logger.comparexmlf1.mailer1 = INFO, email
# turn off additivity
log4j.logger.comparexmlf1.mailer1 = false

Comment: The SMTP Appender provided by log4j by default doesn tsupport set up of  STARTTTLS command to initiate SMTP Session.. you could ...either you have to set it up by writing your own program or you can use https://code.google.com/p/log4j-gmail-smtp-appender/ for gmail